# Color OS - App crashes when loading RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to figure out why the app is crashing when trying to load a RecyclerView with a list of countries. Its simple and uses ListAdapter with a ViewHolder. Its working fine in Google Pixel, OnePlus, Motorola, Nokia, Huwaii, Xiaomi and new Samsung phones but crashes in Color OS phones (Oppo, RealMe etc) and some of the One UI (Samsung Galaxy A10) phones.

I have no idea why it crashes as there is really nothing in the code that could crash and it is working fine in other phones..

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Please help.
Thank you.

API Level: 26 (Android 8.0, Oreo). I am using ViewBinding and LiveData too.

Adapter is like this:

```
public class CountryAdapter extends ListAdapter<Country, CountryHolder>{
       public CountryAdapter(@NonNull DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Country> diffCallback){
        ....
       }
       ...
}
```

If any more details are required, please let me know..

Comment: Can you please post your error log in the question?

Comment: Unfortunately the physical device is not with me, neither I could find an emulator. It crashed in a customer phone.

Comment: Do you have crashlytics integrated?

Comment: Oh.. not sure how to use it. Let me google. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Found the issue, thank you so much. It was crashing because it couldn't find country code ZG. Crashlytics worked. Thanks a lot mate.

Answer (score 0):

By adding Crashlytics to my app, I could figure out what went wrong in the client's phone. In fact, it was not related to RecyclerView but was an error related to Locale. Fixed it and works fine. Thanks to Mayur Gajra for the hint. Saved a lot of time.